# Though some may find me lacking, others call me less

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, literature

> Though some may find me lacking
>   Others call me less
>   Some may think I’m both
>   Despite my flame and my finesse
>
> Family, no family, mind's asunder
>   Feel the elements, hear the thunder
>   They will rue the day, I have a plan
>   I will find and kill ___ _________
>
> And tales are told across the land
>   But folly of man is left to stand
>   And though I sympathize no more
>   You know nothing, wait for the door

Who am I?

**Hint 1**

> As Dr. T guessed, it's referring to a character in the Kingkiller Chronicles

Comment: Are the number of blank spaces relevant (3 and 9)?

Comment: @gnovice I didn't count the number of underscores when I typed them, I just meant two words with the first word being shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is:

> Kvothe, the main character of The Kingkiller Chronicle by Patrick Rothfuss

Though some may find me lacking
Others call me less
Some may think I’m both
Despite my flame and my finesse

> At his peak, he was known as Kvothe the Arcane, Bloodless, and Kingkiller. But these days he simply goes as "Kote", a mere innkeeper, who seems to be lacking much of his legendary skill in sympathy. He is also Edema Ruh, which is as low-born as you can get.
>  There are also some hints that his mother was heir to the Lackless family before eloping with a trouper.
>  Kvothe's hair is bright red and often compared to a flame. And he has always had finesse in language, music, and sympathy.

Family, no family, mind's asunder
Feel the elements, hear the thunder
They will rue the day, I have a plan
I will find and kill ___ _________

> The blanks would be "The Chandrian."
>  These are the evil beings who murdered Kvothe's entire troupe (no family) because his father sang a song about them, although he will always have family in the Ruh.
>  Kvothe can break his mind into many more pieces than most people can when practicing sympathy. He knows the Name of the Wind and can call wind and lightning (elements). And he has trained with the Ademre where he was given the name Maedre (meaning Thunder).
>  He is on a mission to learn more about The Chandrian and destroy them.

And tales are told across the land
But folly of man is left to stand
And though I sympathize no more
You know nothing, wait for the door

> Everybody has heard tales of Kvothe Arcane, in fact he loved encouraging rumors about himself to spread while at the University. The entire series is really a story about storytelling. He's currently reciting his story to Chronicler. He's a living legend.
>  However, he has hung up his sword on a stand engraved with the word "Folly".
>  And again, he has lost his adeptness in sympathy.
>  Kvothe has been wondering what is behind the doors of stone in the library, and we, the readers, are waiting for *The Doors of Stone*, the final book in the trilogy!

Well done on the riddle, I love the books but definitely needed some help from a Kingkillers wiki :)

Comment: That's Perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

Can't shake the feeling that this has to do with

> Game of Thrones

Spoilers ahead (not just the puzzle kind):

Who am I?

> Daenerys Targaryen

Though some may find me lacking,
others call me less

> Lacking and less referring to her arguable unfitness to rule to some in the show, between being a female (less than a man) and not having the right to rule (lacking).

some may think i’m both,
despite my flame and my finesse

> Flame is an obvious reference to her title and dragons.

Family, no family, mind's asunder
Feel the elements, hear the thunder

> Her family lineage is what she feels gives her the right to the throne. However she also believes herself to be the last of her family; and instead refers to her dragons as children. Targaryen's are known for going crazy, and she may be showing symptoms herself. The elements and thunder can refer to the fire and roar of her dragons as well as a reference to her title as Daenerys Stormborn.

They will rue the day, I have a plan
I will find and kill ___ _________

> She certainly has a plan, to take the iron throne and kill a few people along the way, but not sure what exactly goes in the blanks (Cersei Lan? lol)

And tales are told across the land, 
but folly of man is left to stand

> This is the shakiest part for me, can't really make a direct connection except perhaps Daenerys' frustration that Cersei (or Lannisters in general) are still in power of the throne despite stories of illegitimacy, the cruel acts committed, and that ultimately she feels her family was robbed of the throne in the first place.

and though I sympathize no more, 
you know nothing, wait for the door

> Hard not to see the GoT references here, though admittedly Daenerys herself is not wise to either 'You know nothing' or 'Hold the door', it still makes sense as general references to the series.

Feel free to help me fill in the gaps. Also (as some may notice) this is my first time posting here in a looong time, so forgive my formatting.

Comment: Good guess, but the last line is a bit of a red herring....what I wanted to get across just happened to be worded in that way but it isn't referencing game of thrones ;)

Answer (score 1):

I will take a wild swing at this...
My daughter told me about some books she was reading and thought I would like as well.  I had a look at the first one and was not interested but I do recall some of it.

The book was:

> the Kingkiller Chronicle

There was a maiden in the story named:

> Denna

Who was a member of the:

> Lackless family

One of the mysteries in the story had to do with what was in a magical box and what was hidden behind a:

> Stone door

I lost interest in the story because it seemed to be nothing more than a number of tantalizing hints strung together to keep the reader thinking they would learn the secrets but they actually didn't know anything...

Comment: Right book, wrong person :] I'm sorry to hear that you didn't like the book though, you should have definitely read the second one because it gets even better! I was reading the third time and it inspired me to make this.

Comment: I don't think Denna was a member of the Lackless family?

Comment: I guess I would have to borrow the book from my daughter again.  Somebody else may know who the person is.